# How does GnuPG outputs to console while stdout and stderr are both redirected to /dev/null

Tags: io-redirection, gpg, file-descriptors

Example :

```
bash$ gpg --batch --edit-key alice quit >/dev/null 2>&1
Secret key is available.

pub  2048R/9F07612A  created: 2017-06-20  expires: never       usage: SCEA
                     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
sub  2048R/23B3A24B  created: 2017-06-20  expires: never       usage: SEA 
[ultimate] (1). alice (alice's key) <alice@foo.bar>
```

I know that using `--batch` will do the job.

But my question is more **"how does GnuPG achieves this '*output anyway*' feature"**?

Comment: FYI - Redirect as expected under OSX 10.11 (El Capitan) and NetBSD 7.0.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably by writing to `/dev/tty` or equivalent, that's what `ssh` does.

```
$ hi() { echo hello > /dev/tty; }
$ hi &>/dev/null 
hello
```

On Linux, at least, opening `/dev/tty` [opens the controlling terminal of the process](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html).

Comment: [source reference](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=common/ttyio.c;hb=2975eee420007557a138445d0505f1d590d88d7e#l91)